# How to fix a subtraction operation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, operators

I am trying a simple subtraction operation: water_to_add should be dna_to_add minus final_volume which is 60.0. However the results for dna_to_add and water_to_add have been the same. Why my "minus" operation for water_to_add is not working?

BTW, dna_to_add is being calculated correctly.

```
concentration_ng_ul = input("Enter Concentration (ng/ul): ")
size = input("Enter Size (bp): ")
c= float(concentration_ng_ul)
s = float(size)

c_ug_ul = c/1000.0

pmol_DNA_ul = c_ug_ul*1515.15*1/s

fmol_DNA_ul = pmol_DNA_ul/1000.0
fmol_DNA_goal = 20.0
final_volume = 60.0

dna_to_add = (fmol_DNA_goal)*(final_volume/fmol_DNA_ul)
print('DNA_ul',dna_to_add)

water_to_add = (dna_to_add)-(final_volume)
print('Water_ul',water_to_add)
```

Comment: What are the values that you enter when you see the same results?

Comment: Please provide the inputs that you pass to your program when you are running it. What do you mean by "_the results... have been the same_"? What do you mean by "_not working_"?